# Error CORS en redireccion a Mercadopago

Tags: nodejs, url, mercadopago, cors

Tengo un proyecto backend desarrollado para un curso y le quiero agregar una opcion de pago con *mercadopago* y obtengo el siguiente error

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/checkout/v1/redirect?pref_id=1460943817-641c1d86-9039-43c0-b823-6b551baae08e' (redirected from 'https://backendproject-production-c244.up.railway.app/ticket/64d4efdba84d944152563bef/purchase-redirect') from origin 'https://backendproject-production-c244.up.railway.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

El tema es que si hago click en el link de mercadopago y lo abro manualmente en una pestaña aparte funciona perfecto el resto de los pasos, solo me falta ese.

Esta es la config de mi `CORS` que tengo en mi archivo `app.js`

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*", 
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  credentials: true
}));
```

Y este es el controlador que redirecciona a mercadopago

```
export const createTicketAndRedirect = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const cartId = req.params.cid;

    // Encuentra el cartID en userModel
    const user = await userModel.findOne({ cartID: cartId });

    if (user) {
      // Obtiene los productos del carrito utilizando cartModel y el cartID del usuario
      const cart = await cartModel.findOne({ cartID: cartId }).lean().populate("products.product");

      if (cart) {
        if (cart.products.length > 0) {
          const ticketProducts = [];
          let subtotal = 0;

          // Calcula el subtotal y arma la lista de productos del ticket
          cart.products.forEach(product => {
            const productData = {
              name: product.product.title,
              price: product.product.price,
              quantity: product.quantity,
              totalPrice: product.quantity * product.product.price
            };

            ticketProducts.push(productData);
            subtotal += productData.totalPrice;
          });

          const total = subtotal; 

          // Calcula el valor total de todos los productos
          const totalAPagar = ticketProducts.reduce((total, product) => total + product.totalPrice, 0);

          // Obtiene el nombre del comprador y la fecha de compra
          const purchaser = user.email;
          const purchase_datetime = new Date();

          const ticketID = uuidv4();

          // Crea el ticket en la base de datos utilizando ticketModel
          const ticket = await ticketModel.create({
            _id: ticketID,
            products: ticketProducts,
            subtotal: subtotal,
            total: total,
            totalAPagar: totalAPagar, 
            purchaser: purchaser,
            purchase_datetime: purchase_datetime
          });

          // Crear preferencia de pago en MercadoPago
          const mercadoPagoItems = cart.products.map(product => ({
            title: product.product.title,
            unit_price: product.product.price,
            currency_id: "ARS", 
            quantity: product.quantity,
          }));

          const preference = await mercadopago.preferences.create({
            items: mercadoPagoItems,
            notification_url: "https://tu-domino.com/webhook",
            back_urls: {
              success: "https://backendproject-production-c244.up.railway.app/thankyou",
              pending: "https://e720-190-237-16-208.sa.ngrok.io/pending",
              failure: "https://e720-190-237-16-208.sa.ngrok.io/failure",
            },
          });

          // Redirigir al usuario a la página de pago de MercadoPago
          res.redirect(preference.body.init_point);

        } else {
          res.status(400).send("No se encuentran productos agregados al carrito.");
        }
      } else {
        res.status(400).send("El Carrito solicitado no contiene productos.");
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).send("El cartID no está asociado a ningún usuario.");
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error en createTicket:", err);
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
};
```